# Installing nvm in aws Error: UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate

I tried to install one module with npm in AWS but I'm getting Error:

> UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY

I tried to set the registry with npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/ and disabling the ssl with npm config set strict-ssl false

Also using the var export NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=/etc/pki/tls/certs/

But when I try to install de package after of that, is still looking for in the HTTPS repository:

ec2-user:~/environment/dapp $ sudo npm install -g ganache-cli
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ganache-cli

And getting the SSL error.

Do you know how to disable it in an AWS ec2 running in cloud9?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In EC2, try the installation command with out sudo in front
example, $ npm install package-name